# Standards for drawing chemical molecules

Tags: molecules, structural-formula, reference-request

I'll preface this by saying I haven't had a chemistry class in 10 years and molecular structures are not my thing. But I'm submitting a revision to a journal paper where I need to include figures of molecules and I need to make sure I get it right so I don't get nit-picked apart for it.

Is there a standard/guide/list of rules for how to create chemical molecule figures like [the one below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMX)?

[image]

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of rules but as an example of things I would need to know:

1. Should I include the carbon atoms in the ring drawing?
2. At what angle should the entire molecule be drawn (I've seen rigid-body rotated versions of the same molecule before)?

Rather than answering those specific questions, I'd like to know if anybody (IUPAC maybe?) has a standard for drawing these figures.

Comment: It's also worth noting that most chemistry journals publish their own instructions for authors including guidelines for figures and chemical structures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it happens, there are a set of quite involved documents from the "IUPAC Chemical Nomenclature and Structure Representation Division".

[There's a list here](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/keywords/IUPAC_Chemical_Nomenclature_and_Structure_Representation_Division/), but to avoid later link-rot, they are currently:

- Jonathan Brecher Graphical representation of stereochemical configuration (IUPAC Recommendations 2006) *2006*, Vol. 78, Issue 10, pp. 1897-1970
- Richard M. Hartshorn, Evamarie Hey-Hawkins, René Kalio and G. Jeffery Leigh: Representation of configuration in coordination polyhedra and the extension of current methodology to coordination numbers greater than six (IUPAC Technical Report)
  *2007*, Vol. 79, Issue 10, pp. 1779-1799
- W. Mormann and K.-H. Hellwich: Structure-based nomenclature for cyclic organic macromolecules (IUPAC Recommendations 2008) *2008*, Vol. 80, Issue 2, pp. 201-232
- Jonathan Brecher: Graphical representation standards for chemical structure diagrams (IUPAC Recommendations 2008) *2008*, Vol. 80, Issue 2, pp. 277-410
- Andrey Yerin, Edward S. Wilks, Gerard P. Moss and Akira Harada: Nomenclature for rotaxanes and pseudorotaxanes (IUPAC Recommendations 2008) *2008*, Vol. 80, Issue 9, pp. 2041-2068

Comment: I found "Graphical representation standards for chemical structure diagrams" to be exactly what I was looking for and the most helpful of the bunch. But man is it dry reading!